# ScanSafe marks site as virus

Tags: web-hosting, azure, web

Recently I moved my site from DSL line to Azure VM and just yesterday one of the users reported that the site has been marked as unsafe ("Reputation-Viruses") by ScanSafe. Do you know whether it is possible to somehow verify this information, get detailed report that would indicate the reason why my site has been listed and delist it (after correcting the issue)?

Comment: Most likely it's because you were unfortunate to get an IP address that was listed on ScanSafe. The easiest way would be to get a different IP address (release the one you have, or terminate/spin up a new VM).

Comment: It looks more like a workaround than a real solution (even though its helpful, thanks). Any idea how to do it the proper way? Maybe even one of the sites on this IP has some virus, but it is certainly not the site that is being blocked. BTW, are you sure they are blocking based on IP addresses, not domain names?

Comment: You should contact these ScanSafe people. I've never heard of them before today, though I see that Cisco bought them. Also, blocking websites by IP address is more common than it should be; Malwarebytes Pro does it, for instance, which makes it kind of useless.

Comment: Easier said than done - I cannot find and contact information whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for your site/IP here:

http://www.senderbase.org/

Regards,
Simon